# FIRAuthUI FriendlyPix project error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've downloaded [FriendlyPix proj](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix) on git and used pod install, but for some reason I get the error below. The error is that signInProvider and authUI method in FIRAuthUI is not found

[image]

On the left in the Pods folder, FirebaseUI is installed, and I looked online at FireAuthUI docs and those properties like signInProviders exist in the library http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FirebaseUI/0.4.0/Classes/FIRAuthUI.html

I'm not exactly sure why I'm receiving those errors, I also have the @import FirebaseAuthUI; and didn't modify anything. FIRAuthUI is version 0.5.5, xcode version 7+, and cocoa version 1.0.0

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     //Here The error codes occur: Error: Property 'signInProviders' not found on object of type 'id' 
     [FIRAuthUI authUI].signInProviders = @[[[FIRGoogleAuthUI alloc initWithClientID:[FIRApp defaultApp].options.clientID]];

     //Error: No known class method for selector 'authUI'
     [FIRAuthUI authUI].termsOfServiceURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://firebase.google.com/terms/"];

     self.authStateDidChangeHandle = [[FIRAuth auth]
     addAuthStateDidChangeListener:^(FIRAuth *_Nonnull auth, FIRUser *_Nullable user) {
                                 if (user) {
                                   [self signedIn:user];
                                 }
                               }];
```

}

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe as of 0.5.x the methods changed from `authUI` to `defaultAuthUI` and `signInProviders` to `providers`:

```
[FIRAuth defaultAuthUI].providers = @[/* add providers */];
```

Should work!